# Why/How python3 schedules threads in creation order?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading, gil

The following code prints `False` on *python27* and `True` on *python36* on my **Mac**.

```
from threading import Thread


def make_huge_list(amount):
    my_list = []

    def add_num(num):
        my_list.append(num)

    threads = [Thread(target=add_num, args=(i,)) for i in range(amount)]

    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads: t.join()

    return my_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # check the output is ordered
    print(make_huge_list(100000) == list(range(100000)))
```

I know that **GIL** improvements were added in *python3* for better scheduling/fairness. I'm puzzled on how/why this codes prints `True` on *python36*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python3.2 the GIL handling was changed (read more [here](https://callhub.io/understanding-python-gil/))

the change that mainly effects the code above is how the GIL is reacquired after a release.

Before the change python would have release the GIL and all threads would battle for it, which means that after the **main thread** creates a thread it releases the GIL and try to reacquire it, which means the schedule might look like this

MT -> T1 -> MT ->T2 -> MT -> MT ->T4 -> T3 ...

In python3.2 a thread releases the GIL and signals other threads to take it, so it won't take the GIL again, the schedule will look like this:

MT -> T1 -> MT ->T2 -> MT -> T3 -> MT -> T4 ...

only two threads will be active in the same time :)